# A theorem about functions of self-adjoint operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics, definition

It is very common (see e.g. page 18 of Ballentine's *Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development*) for the following development to take place. We couch the discussion in Dirac's bra-ket notation noting that (as I am not really capable of) it is possible to make this precise in the rigged Hilbert space formalism (for operators with continuous spectra etc.).

It is a fact that self-adjoint operator $A$ admits a complete eigenbasis, so that it is a subsequent *theorem* that we can write $A$ as $$A = \sum a_i |a_i \rangle \langle a_i |.$$ It is then very common to say that this motivates the *definition* of a function of such an operator, $f(A)$, by $$f(A) = \sum f(a_i)|a_i \rangle \langle a_i |.$$

My question surrounds the definition of the function of an oeprator. My suspicion is that there is a different *definition* of $f(A)$ from operator theory, and that the definition I have quoted above is equivalent to said definition via some *theorem*. Is that indeed the case?

Comment: Most take this [Sylvester's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_formula) as a definition. The projection operators you resolved the identity to are the analog of Frobenius covariants for matrices. You have qualms?

Comment: @CosmasZachos But doesn't even writing the formula presuppose that the expansion converges? Also, surely it is possible to define functions of (some) non-self adjoint operators -- I would then expect that in the particular case of a self-adjoint operator that definition would reduce to this one, no?

Comment: @TobiasFünke I suppose (1) because this definition only works for self-adjoint operators and I have to imagine that functions of non-self-adjoint operators are sometimes well-defined and (2) there is no establishment of existence (convergence) in the definition given. The Hilbert space requirement is that the sum of moduli squared of coefficients be finite but is that clear? Again, this is just a suspicion from someone who only knows real analysis at the level of Baby Rudin, and certainly no functional analysis.

Comment: Sylvester's theorem works for diagonalizable operators. Convergence issues belong to MSE, I fear.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I understand and am happy to post there, but I just want to say that by saying "works" we are tacitly saying that the expression I gave for $f(A)$ comports with *some other* definition.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean with other definition. *What* other definition? You're right that functions of operators can be defined for non-selfadjoint operators, cf. exponential of a matrix. And one can define series in terms of bounded operators, for example. But what is the question here, actually?

Comment: As I suggested, this formula is taken as *the* definition, and any isolated divergences of $f(a_i)$ are finessed by the effective measure of the spectral resolution of $A_i$, rigging and all...

Comment: @TobiasFünke In terms of a commonly used example in QM, we might have (with the usual definitions) $U = \exp(-iHt/\hbar)$ which is *defined* in terms of a power series expansion of powers of $H$. It seems to me that it is a *theorem* that I also have $\exp(-iHt/\hbar) = \sum \exp(-iE_nt/\hbar)|E_n \rangle \langle E_n|$. Again, all of this is just a suspicion so I may indeed not be making sense.

Comment: No, I don't think it is defined like this; note that $H$ is usually unbounded. Usually it is defined in terms of [spectral theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408722/functions-of-operators) or discussed in the context of Stone's theorem.

Comment: Point well taken, thank you. The mathematics there is above my head but I guess the crux is that there *is* some other definition with the result I noted as a subsequent theorem.

Comment: Or maybe I see what you mean: the link you gave is the mathematically precise way of writing the expansion in terms of outer products that I wrote?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get exactly what the question is, so here is my last comment (I guess someone else can answer your question; also note that I am not a mathematician etc.): You can define functions of operators for which the spectral theorem applies (not only self-adjoint operators), see e.g. the link in my previous comment. You can also define (positive integer) powers of operators, e.g. $A^2 := A\circ A$ - in both cases one has to take care of the domains etc; you can also define power series of bounded operators, for example. There are probably even more possible definitions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to define functions of operators. A common example is via a power series, e.g.
$$\exp(A) := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} A^k$$

One can show that if the radius of convergence of the series of the original function $f$ is $R$, then the corresponding operator $f(A)$ is well-defined iff the operator norm $\Vert A\Vert_{op} < R$.

The requirement that $A$ be bounded (and that $\Vert A\Vert_{op}$ be within the radius of convergence of the Taylor series) is very limiting.  There are several important alternatives (e.g. the [holomorphic functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus), the [continuous functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus), the [polynomial functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus)), but the most important is the [Borel functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus) which works via the spectral theorem. If $A$ is a normal operator, then it can be expressed as
$$A = \int_{\sigma(A)}\lambda \  \ \mathrm dP^A(\lambda) $$
where $\sigma(A)\subseteq \mathbb C$ is the spectrum of $A$ and $P^A$ is its [projection-valued measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure).  Note that this reduces to the familiar expression
$$A = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} \lambda |\lambda \rangle\langle \lambda|$$
if $\sigma(A)$ is purely discrete and its eigenspaces are one-dimensional. In this language, given a Borel-measurable function $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$, we have that

$$f(A) := \int_{\sigma(A)} f(\lambda) \ \mathrm dP^A(\lambda) \rightsquigarrow \sum_{\lambda\in \sigma(A)} f(\lambda) |\lambda\rangle\langle \lambda|$$

This is the definition of a function of a possibly-unbounded operator which is most commonly used in quantum mechanics (e.g. in [Stone's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups)).

Comment: In your last equation, is $:=$ meant to say "is defined by"? I suppose given your last written line but wanted to make sure. In that case I guess the "definition" I noted is just that, a definition.

Comment: @EE18 Yes, that is meant to be a definition (as is the first expression I wrote at the top).