# How to deal with functions of multiple (self-adjoint) operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

My question is related to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/745771/a-theorem-about-functions-of-self-adjoint-operators) question.

All is fine and dandy when we write down the formula
$$f(A) = \sum f(a_i)|a_i \rangle \langle a_i |,$$

for $A$, let's say, self adjoint, which I suppose is a mnemonic to some extent saying "for $f(A)$, consider the corresponding function on $\mathbb{C}$, $f$, and put this evaluated at the eigenvalues of $A$ as the factor before each corresponding projector".

No problem. But what if I see an expression where I have something like $f(A,B)$, where $A,B$ are each self-adjoint? I can imagine two cases:

(1) $A,B$ commute, so that, using the simultaneous eigenbasis, I can still make sense of
$\sum f(a_i,b_i)|a_i \rangle \langle a_i | $.

(2) $A,B$ do not commute. I am stumped as to what happens here -- do we simply say that $f(A,B)$ is not well-defined? I am not there yet but I have heard such contructions come up in the theory of scattering.

My question is what are the correct definitions in cases (1) and (2)?

Edit: I suppose depending on the structure of $f$, the argument may or may not be self-adjoint (e.g. if $f(A,B) = A-aB, a \in \mathbb{R}$ then we can take the eigenbasis of $C := A-aB$. But if $a \in \mathbb{C}$ then there is no guarantee in general that such a basis exists. I suppose such a case is a function of an operator which is not self-adjoint so perhaps we needn't worry (since such a function might not be well-defined in the first place).

Comment: What exactly is the use case here? Where do such functions appear such that $f(A,B)$ isn't a polynomial in $A$ and $B$ (in which case you don't need functional calculus at all) or the function of a single self-adjoint combination of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I was told that the expression $\delta(A-\alpha I)$ appears in the study of scattering. It's not clear to me that $\alpha$ need be real in this context (I've not yet studied scattering). At any rate, even without the use case, the question should stand on its own, no? Perhaps the answer (or part of it) is that such a construction never arises? Edit: A case where $f$ is a polynomial with complex coefficients does not appear to me to follow easily.

Comment: A δ function is but the integral of exponentials which are well defined this way.

Comment: My point is that $f(A, B)$ will usually not appear without context (e. g. an ordering prescription) that will *tell* you how to interpret it; for polynomials $A^n B^m A^k$ is just applying A k times, then B m times, then A n times, no functional calculus needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short $f(A, B)$ is not defined for $A$ and $B$ operators.

By the notation $f(A, B)$ I'm imagining a polynomial function $f:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$. Something like
$$
f(x, y) = xy = yx
$$

Obviously this makes sense for scalars but if we "plug in" operators instead of scalars for the function arguments we then get something like

$$
f(A, B) \stackrel{?}{=}AB \stackrel{?}{=} BA
$$

Basically the notation $f(A,B)$ doesn't give us enough information to know whether $f(A, B) = AB$ or $f(A, B)=BA$.

That said, if the function $f$ was originally defined on some sort of non-commutative ring or something then that means it already had some ordering associated on it so then $f(A, B)$ would be defined.

The above addresses case (2) when $[A, B]\not=0$. As for case (1) if $[A, B] =0$ then sure, $f(A, B)$ is in general defined because it doesn't matter if it was $f(x, y) =xy$ or $yx$. But nonetheless, if you're dealing with operators, it's probably best practice to avoid notation like $f(A, B)$ unless you're very clear about what you mean by it.

Answer (score 2):

This illustrates the point in terms familiar to most physicists. Indeed, your (1) makes sense, as you anticipated. For example, for $A=\hat x$ and $B=g(\hat x)$, you of course have $$
f(A,B)= \int\!\!dx~ |x\rangle f(x,g(x))~\langle x|~~.
$$

In your case (2), take the emblematic pair of noncommuting operators, $A=\hat x$ and $B=\hat p$. It's been proven dozens of times on this site that
$$
\hat x= \int\!\!dx~ |x\rangle  x\langle x|,\\
\hat p= \int\!\!dp~ |p\rangle  p\langle p| \\ 
=\int\!\!dpdxdx'~|x\rangle\langle x |p\rangle  p\langle p|x'\rangle \langle x'|
\\  =\int\!\!dx~ |x\rangle (-i\hbar \partial_x)\langle x| .
$$
The eigenvectors of $\hat x$ do not coincide with those of $\hat p$, but the latter may be "rotated" to the former, and, at the end of the day, yield the 2nd expression in terms of the former (eigenvectors), without  a visible connection to its set of eigenvectors.

You now readily get, e.g.,
$$
A^5 B^2= \hat x ^5 \hat p ^2=-\hbar^2 \int\!\!dx~ |x\rangle x^5   \partial_x^2\langle x| ,
$$
etc, unambiguous, in standard practice.

Fittingly, this is unequal to
$$B A^5 B= -\hbar^2 \int\!\!dx~ |x\rangle \partial_x x^5   \partial_x\langle x|,$$ or
$$B A B A^4=-\hbar^2 \int\!\!dx~ |x\rangle \partial_x x\partial_x x^4   \langle x|,$$ etc, in associative but non-commutative [Heaviside calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_calculus), as you may trivially verify  through these maps.

***Takeaway***: You cannot talk about the eigenvalues of *A* and *B* in the same breath, but you may still use the  eigenvectors of either to define a noncommutative function of them provided you have specified an ordering prescription for them, i.e. you define $f(x,-i\hbar\partial_x)$ here. You will *not* discover a quantization map this way: you will dictate it.

- Due diligence: Convince yourself this works for *any* polynomial of *A* and *B* in *any* ordering, so any noncommutative polynomial, hence any noncommutative Taylor series for the $f(A,B)$ with any ordering of *A,B* you chose and specify. Exponentials of non commuting variables occur routinely, while δ functions are but integrals of exponentials; the coefficients in the exponent need *not* be real.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure this answers my question. In this case you've "multiplied" the expansions of the two operators together which is quite apart from using the formula in terms of an eigendecomposition of some function of two (or more) operators. They are simply different scenarios entirely. You've written $f(A,B) = f_1(A)f_2(B)$ and then "rotated" the latter expression as you say. But not every $f$ can be so expressed.

Comment: No! you misunderstood... I have "rotated" the eigenvector bases of the two operators into each other by the standard $\langle x|p \rangle$ basis change used universally. *f(A,B)* need *not*, repeat, *not* factorize. Any noncommutative polynomial of *A* s and *B* s is covered in this framework, and any function with a sensible Taylor expansion *ipso facto* . It's not rocket science! All non-pathological physics problems are adequately covered by this framework. Concoction of freak counterexamples 99% of the time relies on popular misunderstandings.

Comment: I added the canonical derivation to emphasize that you really don't work with the eigenvalues of the incompatible operator *B* : you find the equivalent operator in the eigenbasis of *A* !