# Newtonian generalisation of binomial theorem for commuting operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, mathematical-physics, mathematics

Suppose $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ are *commuting* operators on some Hilbert space, $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=0$, chosen suitably to ensure operators $1/\hat{A}$, $1/\hat{B}$ and $\hat{A}/\hat{B}$ are suitably well defined and bounded (for the purposes of convergence - whatever form that may take?). Does the following Newtonian generalisation of the binomial theorem to negative integers hold, and under what conditions might this be valid:

$$(\hat{A}+\hat{B})^{-1}= \frac{1}{\hat{A}}\left(\hat{1}+\frac{\hat{B}}{\hat{A}}\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\hat{A}}\left(\hat{1}-\frac{\hat{B}}{\hat{A}}+\left(\frac{\hat{B}}{\hat{A}}\right)^2 -\left(\frac{\hat{B}}{\hat{A}}\right)^3+\cdots \right)$$

There are many confusion tucked into this query: Is the operator $1/\hat{A}$ typically the "inverse" of the operator $\hat{A}$ under composition? Is the first equality in the above a valid thing to do, and under what conditions is this possible? Is such a series expansion valid given that $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ commute? What other conditions may be necessary?

Comment: [Neumann Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) might be worth to study.

Comment: Regarding the first step: $(A+B)=A(I+A^{-1}B)$ and hence $(A+B)^{-1}=(I+A^{-1}B)^{-1}A^{-1}$ (assuming that all operators are bounded and that all relevant operators are invertible).

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thanks, that's certainly worth a closer look. There, however, they seem to speak of $(A+B)^{-1}$ as the inverse of the operator $A+B$ as opposed to the reciprocal sense to which I refer: $(A+B)^{-1} = \frac{1}{A+B}$. Are these indeed the same thing?

Comment: Well, what do you mean with "the reciprocal"--can you define it?

Comment: @TobiasFünke Given an operator $\hat{X}$ with some spectrum not containing zero, the eigenstates of $\hat{X}$  are also eigenstates of the operator $1/\hat{X}$, except they have reciprocal eigenvalues (in the c-number sense).

Comment: @TobiasFünke Perhaps that is a then a more loose definition than I want to give. I want to define it in the same way that any algebraic function f (inherited from the space of functions on c-numbers) of an operator $\hat{X}$ is defined. How is this typically defined?

Comment: Sorry, but this is an entirely different question of what you have asked here. And it has been asked on PSE before. See e.g [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/745771/a-theorem-about-functions-of-self-adjoint-operators).

Comment: @TobiasFünke My question was largely rhetorical and your response has confused me; my point was that I can't imagine thinking about a definition of what $1/\hat{X}$ truly is beyond the way I have defined it. Is the definition of $1/\hat{X}$ a controversial matter? For the sake of argument, let us suppose that $\hat{X}$ is just the regular position operator. Is the definition of $1/\hat{X}$ somehow ill-defined (assuming we have already excluded zero from the spectrum of $\hat{X}$?

I can ask whether $1/\hat{X} = \hat{X}^{-1}$ in another post, if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I honestly cannot follow the discussion anymore. Someone else might be able to help you. Last comment: Take a hermitian operator $X$ on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space. It has a spectral representation $X=\sum\limits_{x\in \sigma(X)}x\, P_x$, where $\sigma(X)$ denotes the spectrum of $X$, not contianing $0$. Then you inted to define $1/X:=\sum\limits_{x\in \sigma (X)}1/x \, P_x$; nothing wrong with it. I asked you, in a comment I've deleted already because the discussion gets anyway too long, where the difference to $X^{-1}$ is...

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thank you nonetheless. I think, taking that definition, one can indeed argue that $\hat{X}^{-1} = 1/\hat{X}$. Since, $X \circ 1/\hat{X} = \sum_{x,y\in \sigma{X}} x/y P_x P_y = \sum_{x,y\in \sigma{X}} x/y \delta_{x,y} |x\rangle \langle y| = \hat{1}$. I assume this also works if we take a continuous spectra and integrals rather than sums.

Comment: Yes (of course one has to formulate everything properly and then check more closely). But you do not have to assume (and you did not in the question) that the operator is hermitian for talking about inverses... In any case, I think (you should double check) that you can define (for bounded $A$): $1/A:=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (1-A)^k$ if $||1-A||<1$; but as the argument in the Neumann series shows, this is simply $A^{-1}$ again.