When a function of the position operator is self-adjoint?
Consider the position operator defined by
$$\hat{x}\,\psi(x)=x\,\psi(x).$$
Now, for any given function $f(x)$, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for $f$ such that $f(\hat{x})$ is a self-adjoint operator?

Being holomorphic is probably enough https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/745771/291677

Functions of self-adjoint operators can be defined via the spectral theorem. From there it should be clear how to extract the conditions.

Necessary and sufficient conditions on $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ to make $f(A)$ selfadjoint if $A$ is selfadjoint (generally unbounded and defined in a dense domain) are that both
(a) $f$ is real valued
(b) is Borel measurable.
For instance $f$ continuous and real valued is ok.
