How to easily prove that operators in the Heisenberg picture have the same expression through other operators?
I was reading a textbook, and didn't understand this implication. Suppose we have a harmonic oscillator. We know that
$$
a_H = a_S e^{-i\omega t}, a_H^{\dagger} = a_S^{\dagger} e^{i\omega t}
$$
It follows, the, textbook says, that, in analogy to how
$$
x_S = x_0 \frac{a_S + a_S^{\dagger}}{\sqrt{2}},
$$
where
$$
x_0 = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m \omega}} \, ,
$$
the same equality is true for the Heisenberg picture of $x_H$ (where the $S$ is replaced by $H$). How do I prove this in the general case? Is this true for all operators?

Multiply by $e^{\pm i H t/\hbar}$ on the left and hand right hand sides.

Thank you, I understand that this solves this case, but I don't understand if this is true, generally. That's why I asked

@CosmasZachos This $x$ has dimensions of position, so the $x_0$ is needed (it's essentially the zero point motion).

Suppose you can write your general operator as an infinite series of powers of $x$ and $p$...

But x is normally measured in units of $x_0$…

If I understand your question correctly, it can be rephrased as follows:
Suppose that we can write an expression for some Schrödinger picture operator $Y_S$ in terms of some other operator $X_S$ such that:
$$Y_S=f(X_S)$$
Do the Heisenberg picture operators $Y_H$ and $X_H$ then follow the same same relationship:
$$Y_H\stackrel{?}{=}f(X_H)$$
We can demonstrate that this is the case by writing $f$ as a Taylor series and using the fact that the time evolution operator $U$ is unitary.
$$Y_S=f(X_S)\\ \therefore Y_H \equiv U^\dagger Y_S U=U^\dagger f(X_S)U$$
We substitude $f$ with its Taylor series:
$$\therefore Y_H=U^\dagger \left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}X_S^n \right]U $$
And use the linearity of $U$ and $U^\dagger$:
$$\therefore Y_H=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}U^\dagger X_S^nU$$
Note, however, that since $UU^\dagger$ is the identity operator:$$X_H^n=(U^\dagger X_SU)^n=\underbrace{U^\dagger X_SU U^\dagger X_SU...U^\dagger X_SU}_{n \space times}=U^\dagger\underbrace{X_SX_S...X_S}_{n \space times}U=U^\dagger X_S^nU$$
And thus:
$$\therefore Y_H=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}X_H^n=f(X_H)$$
This is what we wanted to show. For simplicity's (and my laziness's) sake I've treated the case where $Y_H$ is expressed in terms of one operator $X_H$. Try to convince yourself that yourself that you can make the same kind of argument for operators like the Hamiltonian $H_H=f(P_H,X_H)$ by using the Taylor series for multiple variables.

Yes, you understood my question correctly) Thank you!! What if $f$ does not equal its' taylor series, though?

I'm not aware of ways to easily generalize this to non-analytic functions $f$ of operators, or if that can even be done since $f(X_S)$ may not even be defined. I do know that one can define functions of Hermitian operators using the spectral decomposition $A=\sum_{k} a_k |k\rangle \langle k | $, in which case one can define $f(A)=\sum_{k} f(a_k) |k\rangle \langle k |$ and make a similar argument, but I am unsure if this applies to functions that don't converge to their Taylor series. Mathematics SE might be more helpful for this.

See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/745771/a-theorem-about-functions-of-self-adjoint-operators?noredirect=1&lq=1


We know that
$$
a_H = a_S e^{-i\omega t}, a_H^{\dagger} = a_S^{\dagger} e^{i\omega t}
$$

OK. And you should also know the general definition of a Heisenberg operator in terms of its Schrodinger operator and the Hamiltonian:
$$
\hat Q_H \equiv e^{i\hat Ht}\hat Q_S e^{-i\hat Ht}\;,
$$
where I set $\hbar=1$ for convenience.
So, given your SHO Hamiltonian and your $a_S$ operator (presumably a lowering operator for the SHO):
$$
\hat a_H = e^{iHt}\hat a_S e^{-iHt} = \hat a_S e^{-i\omega t} 
$$

...
$$
x_S = x_0 \frac{a_S + a_S^{\dagger}}{\sqrt{2}},
$$


...
the same equality is true for the Heisenberg picture of $x_H$ (where the $S$ is replaced by $H$).
...
How do I prove this in the general case?

In general, we have
$$
x_H = e^{iHt}x_S e^{-iHt} = x_0 \frac{e^{iHt}a_S e^{-iHt} + e^{iHt}a_S^{\dagger} e^{-iHt}}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
$$
= x_0 \frac{a_H + a_H^{\dagger}}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
